# Embedding a Webpack asset inside Twig's templated e-mail using Symfony Mailer

Tags: php, symfony, twig, webpack-encore

The [Symfony's mailer documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#id1) says one can embed an image easily:

```
<img
    src="{{ email.image('@images/logo.png') }}"
    alt="Logo">
```

However I have all my assets built by Webpack & Encore. I use the asset manifest file as well, because every asset has a chunkhash in its name.

How to embed an image using Twig in this case? I tried:

```
<img
    src="{{ email.image(asset('build/images/logo.png')) }}"
    alt="Logo">
```

But this doesn't work. I end up with an exception that "a template is missing". This works well of course if I use an image from a static location.

Comment: Have you tried `{{ email.image(asset('build/images/logo.png')) }}`?

Comment: Sure, it won't work this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documentation says: define a Twig namespace that points to whatever directory your images are stored in, for example:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    paths:
        # point this wherever your images live
        public/build/: build
```

next, in your email template:

```
{# '@build/' refers to the Twig namespace defined earlier #}
<img src="{{ email.image('@build/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo">
<img src="{{ email.image('@build/subdir/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo">
```

this will not work if the constructed image has some random suffix, e.g. when `.enableVersioning()` is defined in `webpack.config.js` config file.

---

If you have enabled the versioning strategy, you can do the following:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    paths:
        public/: public
```

and build the template name using the string concat operator `~`:

```
{# '@public' refers to the Twig namespace defined earlier #}
<img src="{{ email.image('@public' ~ asset('build/logo.png')) }}" alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways to get an image in your mail. First is an embedded image and second is just a link to an image somewhere on the net. If you want to embed an image you will have to attach the image to your mail:

```
$attachment = Swift_Image::newInstance($data, $filename, $mimeType)
    ->setDisposition('inline');

$cid = $message->embed($attachment); // Generates "cid:something"
```

Important is to show your image like this:

```
<img src="cid:something" ... />
```

So you have to render your template like this:

```
$twig->render('email/email.html.twig', [
    'cid' => $cid,
    ...
]);
```

and in your twig template:

```
<img src="{{ cid }}" ... />
```

Comment: I don't use Swiftmailer anymore and specifically asked about how to do this in Mailer's "templated e-mails".