# Can i combine webpack 'copyFiles' with twig.paths configuration

Tags: html, css, symfony, webpack, twig

I'm using webpack encore and so this is my webpack.config for copying files :

```
# webpack.config.js
Encore
    // -- 37 lines --
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$/,
        // to path is relative to the build directory
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    })

;
```

All of my images files are in **./assets/images**.

Now i run `yarn watch`

So my images are beeing copyed into **public/build/images** as **manifest.json** shows :

```
# public/build/manifest.json

{
  "build/app.css": "/build/app.css",
  "build/app.js": "/build/app.js",
  "build/mail.css": "/build/mail.css",
  "build/mail.js": "/build/mail.js",
  "build/runtime.js": "/build/runtime.js",
  "build/vendors~app.js": "/build/vendors~app.js",
  "build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf": "/build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.1e59d233.ttf",
  "build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2": "/build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.20fd1704.woff2",
  "build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot": "/build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.8b43027f.eot",
  "build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff": "/build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.f691f37e.woff",
  "build/images/favicon.ico": "/build/images/favicon.c48cee16.ico",                       <-- This one
  "build/images/fontawesome-webfont.svg": "/build/images/fontawesome-webfont.c1e38fd9.svg",
  "build/images/logo.png": "/build/images/logo.63e19ce5.png"                              <-- This one
}
```

Then i try to set aliases in my **twig.yaml** file

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
   default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
   paths:
       '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/images/': images
       '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/': build
```

And i use aliases to get my image in base.html.twig

```
# template/base.html.twig
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset("@images/favicon.ico") }}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I have also tried to use this syntax :

```
# template/base.html.twig
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ "@images/favicon.ico" }}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

But it is not working.

The only syntax which work is :

```
# template/twig.yaml
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset("build/images/favicon.ico") }}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

So what am I doing wrong ?
Is this even possible to use aliases while copying file containing a hash ?
I could use aliasses just before i try using copyFiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer here :

[Embedding a Webpack asset inside Twig's templated e-mail using Symfony Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037781/embedding-a-webpack-asset-inside-twigs-templated-e-mail-using-symfony-mailer)

This is working for me.

Just don't forgot to clean cache (`php bin/console c:c`)

Now my code look like this :

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    paths:
      '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/images/': images
      '%kernel.project_dir%/public/': build
```

```
# templates\Mailer\password_reset.html.twig
...
<img src="{{ email.image('@images/' ~ asset('build/images/logo.png')|split('/')[3]) }}" alt="Logo">
...
```

If you still have an error even after doing that, try to copy/path `config/packages/twig.yaml` into `config/packages/env/twig.yaml` (replace env by your env name)

Even though it is a little bit hacky, it work.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about `email.image` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question: no, you cannot combine webpack `copyFiles` and `twig.paths`.

[Namespaced Twig paths](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/namespaced_paths.html) are only used by the Twig file loader, so it will only works when you will include, import, extend or embed a Twig file.

Comment: Well, i actually find a way to combine it. Look at my answer if you are interrested in. Or I maybe haven't understand what you say.